# How do i match the slug in this regex?

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm trying to get this regex to work where i want `studio` to match `www.mysite.com/[slug]/[slug]/ourclasses`, second slug. This is what i've come up with so far. Problem is that it removes the slug and only returns `www.mysite.com/ourclasses`.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
  '/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/ourclasses?','/index.php?pagename=ourclasses&studio=$matches[1]','top'
);
```

How would i write the regex?

Comment: So you're expected result is : "www.mysite.com/school/[slug]/ourclasses" ?

Comment: Yes, that's what im trying.

Comment: Could you provide from what you're trying to extract it or your whole string is that already ?

Comment: Edited the question a little, since i made a mistake.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question?

Comment: So if i'm understanding it right you want to extract "/[slug]/ourclasses" ?

Comment: Yes. thats correct!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240166/discussion-between-datam-and-mathias5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I believe you're pattern should look like this :

```
(?<=/)\w+(?=/\w+$)
```

Comment: That only returns me back to "www.mysite.com/ourclasses"

Comment: I'm not familiar with wordpress so maybe the source of the problem isn't the regex but your redirection or the way your trying to access the page because that regex does return what you told me you wanted

Comment: Understand. i Tried ^studios/([^/]*)/?/([^/]*)/? wich works, but problem   now is that you can change "ourclasses" to whatever and it will still work. Maybe thats a pointer for you. I understand wordpress, but zero of regex.